# HTTP/2 between Nginx reverse proxy and Express

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, http2

I have an Express web server behind Nginx reverse proxy. 
The Nginx is configured for HTTP/2.
Is it better to leave the default http1 connection between Nginx and Express, or is there worth in upgrading Express to HTTP/2 also?
I guess there'll be some performance loss since SSL is required on both, but don't know whether multiplexing (and other improvements) will make up for it.

Comment: Do you even need https on your backend connections?!

Comment: It's not a requirement, I'm just thinking in terms of performance, I guessed that HTTP2 should be faster even in this backend combo.

Comment: So are your backends hosted in some other datacenter than your frontends? There's little other reason to bother with TLS here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use HTTP/2.0 between nginx reverse-proxy and backend webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/765258/use-http-2-0-between-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-backend-webserver)

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx does not support HTTP/2 for proxy_pass connections](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/923) so this is not an option.

In my opinion, there is not huge reason to have HTTP/2 all the way through, in a similar way that HTTPS is not required all the way through.

For more details see the answers to this identical question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy