# (nginx) is it possible to preserve http protocol?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have a backend server that receives `HTTP/1.1`, `HTTP/2.0 plaintext`, `grpc plaintext over HTTP/2.0` (no tls).

I want to use nginx to receive HTTP request from user (`HTTP/1.1`, `HTTP/2`, etc), and pass to backend, preserving HTTP version without using passthrough.

so, desired state is below.

`1. client <-(HTTP/1.1 plaintext)-> nginx <-(HTTP/1.1 plaintext)-> backend`
`2. client <-(HTTP/2 plaintext)-> nginx <-(HTTP/2 plaintext)-> backend`
`3. client <-(grpc over HTTP/2 plaintext)-> nginx <-(grpc over HTTP/2 plaintext)-> backend`
on a same ip, same port.

is this possible?

Comment: Search is your friend https://serverfault.com/search?q=nginx+reverse+proxy+

Comment: You probably do need passthough because the nginx reverse proxy module and the  [`proxy_http_version`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) directive   only allows you to select HTTP protocol version  `1.0` or  `1.1` and talking to backends with HTTP/2 is not supported at all. See this Q&A https://serverfault.com/questions/765258/use-http-2-0-between-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-backend-webserver